# Line graph with coord_flip and custom text

Tags: r

I would like to produce a line graph that would look like this

[image]

I created a test data frame and plotted it

```
value <- c(75,65,75,32,25,75,57,31,25,25,25,75,75,75,25,75,50,40,75,60)
names <-  paste0("myscore_",letters[1:20])
df <- data.frame(value, names)
df$names <- as.character(df$names)
plot(df$value, type = "o", pch = 18, col = "red")
```

[image]

Now, I would like to make horizontal plot, and also put labels (df$names)
on the y-axis so **my output should look like this**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using `ggplot2` library here is an option:

```
g<-ggplot(data = df, aes(y = value,x= names))+geom_point(color = I("red"))+geom_line(group = I(1),color = I("red"))+theme_bw()+coord_flip()
g
```

To add text you can use:

```
g+annotate(geom = "text", x= ... ,y = ..., label = "your label")
```

#### Edit: Result

[image: Result]

Comment: i would prefer ggplot. But when I use your code, the output are just dots without lines and error appears: geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Comment: I had the same error when I do not include the part `group = I(1)`. I added the result to my post.

Comment: It still produces just dots without lines.

Comment: I've sold problem, I just need to add `group=1`, so code looks like this:

`ggplot(data = df, aes(y = value,x= names,group=1))+geom_point(color = I("red"),shape=23, lwd=3,fill="red")+geom_line(group = I(1),color = I("red"))+theme_bw()+coord_flip()`

One question, do you know how I could put some custom text on right side out of the plot like the example in the first picture?